# How can I switch video output from one graphics card to another (Matrox/GeForce)?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, switchable-graphics, matrox

I have a home server with an integrated graphics adapter (it's some Matrox G200). But I need to drive a 4K-display with it (amongst other duties), so I've installed a GeForce (GT 710).

I'm toying around with 20.04, and I've found that while during the bootup-/BIOS-phase both outputs have a signal (the Matrox is connected via DP/HDMI adapter; the GT 710 via HDMI directly; cables and adapter are tested and known to be working), but once the system's up, only the one on the Matrox seems to be working.
Both cards are recognized by the OS; I've even managed to have both "llvmpipe" as well as "Nvidia GeForce GT 710" show in the "About" window of Ubuntu (at different times, of course). But I have yet to get the GT 710 to properly display a 4K signal.

How can I switch to the "other" graphics card for video output?

It *feels* like the OS is "stuck" on the Matrox card and is not using the other one at all. As if it's a misconfigured multi-display setup with either mirroring (thus it cannot show a 4K signal since not both cards are able to) or "disable second display" active.
Unfortunately, there's not much to be found except for the "Display" settings (which … doesn't even show the two different cards).

All I could find in the forums was about the Intel iGPU and Nvidia Prime; but that doesn't help in my case.
I've tried both without and later with the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed. I even tried to disable the integrated (Matrox) card in the BIOS – but then I got all sorts of *really* strange behaviour…

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're after support you should use a #ubuntu+1 site as *focal fossa* hasn't been released yet, however if you're QA-testing and are seeking help with bug reporting, you can also use #ubuntu-quality on IRC or telegram; for help with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the info and sorry for my mistake. On the other hand: How would you switch graphics card on any previous version of Ubuntu? (You see, it's not like I know how to and suddenly with 20.04 it doesn't work; it's just … I don't know on any version. :-( )